# Convert "2023-03-17T05:52:01.000+0000" to a Date with DataWeave

Tags: datetime, mule, dataweave, mulesoft

I wanted to convert this format to "2023-03-17T05:52:01.000+0000" to Date format.

I tried LocaldateTime it didn't work.

Comment: Kindly avoid using salutations/thanks as per the guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

Comment: LocalDateTime will not work because the date time in the input string already has a timezone. LocalDateTIme is for date-times without a timezone.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer [this](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-cookbook-format-dates) documentation for conversion. It contains almost all formatting options for datetime. For you string you can use the following

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
"2023-03-17T05:52:01.000+0000" as DateTime{format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSxx"}
```

Comment: Because the input is a String it has to be converted to a DateTime, so that every character is accounted for. Once it is a DateTime it can be converted to a Date to preserve only the date part. Note that because this script has a JSON output the Date is converted automatically to a String (JSON doesn't has a Date type). If you want to use the date later it would be better to use application/java as the output format.

Comment: I got so confused for a minute. I did not remember adding Date. It seems like it was added after edits from someone

Comment: It is not wrong if the question is how to convert to date only. If DateTime is ok then it can be removed. The question is ambiguous and didn't provide details of the expected output. You could present both examples in your answer.